# converting clustered index into non-clustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

Is it possible to convert a clustered index to non clustered index or 
non clustered index to clustered index in sql server 2005.

Please convert this query into clustered index:

```
create index index1 on mytable(firstcolumn)
```

Please convert this query into non clustered index:

```
create clustered index clusindex1 on mytable(cluscolumn)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is more to it than meets the eye

to create a clustered index

```
drop index mytable.clusindex1 
go

create clustered index clusindex1 on mytable(cluscolumn)
```

to create a non clustered index

```
drop index mytable.clusindex1 
go

create index clusindex1 on mytable(cluscolumn) --non clustered is default
```

having said that, you can only have one clustered index per table, so if you try to drop an index and recreate it as a clustered index it will fail if you already have a clustered index. Whenever you drop a clustered index all non clustered indexes will also be dropped and recreated pointing to the heap, and then again dropped and recreated when you create the clustered index, now pointing to the clustered index (look up the WITH DROP_EXISTING clause)

I would say lookup how indexing works in Books On Line before you start dropping and recreating indexes

Comment: If you add an index with all columns (either in the index, or as included columns), that's basically the same as a second clustered index

Comment: That won't work if you table is over 900 bytes wide or if you have over 16 columns in your table

Comment: You can have up to 1023 included columns of any width AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't queries; they are DDL commands.
Drop and recreate the indexes as desired, like so:

```
drop index mytable.index1
go

create nonclustered index index1 on mytable (firstcolumn asc)
go
```

Answer (score -1):

I also wanted to know whether a clustered index could be converted (altered) to be a non-clustered index. I don't believe this can be done. The existing clustered index has to first be dropped and then the new non-clustered index (possibly with the same name as the clustered index) has to be created. The same is true for converting a non-clustered index to a clustered index.

I have no idea why you're asking for the 'queries' to be converted, but @Tahbaza is correct in that the code you included in your question aren't really queries. They are T-SQL statements for making changes to 'data definitions' (i.e. the schema [structure] of your database).